# Relational objects in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, relational

I have two classes that define Video and Cue objects. I get my data through an JSON API. The backend is written in Rails and has a one-to-many relationship between Video and Cues.

The data I get is structured like this:

```
{ "true":
  [
      {
        "id" : 3,
        "title" : "My Title"
        [
            { "cues":
              [
                  {
                      "id": 117,
                      "time" : "12.81",
                      "video_id" : 3
                  },
                  {
                      "id": 118,
                      "time" : "14.34",
                      "video_id" : 3
                  }
              ]
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a method in Video.m that gets the JSON array, puts it in a dictionary and converts the dictionary to an array of Video objects.

```
+(id) getVideos {
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/myEndPoint"];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *videoDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

    NSMutableArray *videos = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in videoDictionary[@"true"]) {
        NSString *title = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];
        Video *newVideo = [[Video alloc] initWithTitle:title];
        [videos addObject: newVideo];
    }

    return videos;

}
```

How should I format the cues so that I can get specific cues from a Video, like in a relational sort of way if possible, if not then just the best practise. In Rails it would be video.cues. Can I do this in Objective C?

Would be perfect if I could end up having the ability to do something like:

```
Cue *currentCue = video.cues[0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property to your Video class: `NSArray *cues`. And change your init method to `initWithTitle:(NSString*)title andCues:(NSArray*)cues`. That way you'll be able to do exactly that: `video.cues[0]`

Comment: Would I declare it as `@property (nonatomic, strong)` in the `Video.h` file? Or weak?

Comment: yes, strong property so the Video object owns it. And yes, you declare it in the Video.h file. Note that by just defining cues as an NSArray, you could pass anything there, so a good implementation would do some type-checking before actually using the objects in the cues array (checking that video.cues[0] is actually a Cue).